# Windows 10 notification bar vanishes suddenly and never open by click on it

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I am in windows 10 os.

[image: Notification Bar]

When i click on notification area (1), it is displayed for less than 5 seconds and vanishes suddenly and never display by click on (1) again.
Also when i right click on (1) and choose `Open Action Center` nothing happens.
I tried to change it's timer - Problem is still there.
What is wrong about it and how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like it may be crashing. Perhaps take a look in Event Viewer in the Application log. Do you have any desktop customization software installed?

Comment: @Daniel B Do you have any desktop customization software installed? Not at all. My windows 10 is new.

Comment: My windows 10 is new.   .......   It might have had an installation error (possible). Run DISM and SFC (easy)  .  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John Thanks for the advice